# Enable Rating Feature Sharepoint 2010

Tags: .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I red article how to active Rating feature in sharepoint 2010. But unfortunately I have the problem that I my Rating Settings are missing from General Settings in Document library settings. Then I saw on the bottom of the article the following.

*SharePoint 2010 rating settings not available? Here is how to activate rating feature:
Don't have "Rating Settings" appear on lists/libraries settings? Enable Rating feature to fix SharePoint 2010 rating settings missing issue:*

```
Enable-SPFeature Ratings -url http://site-collection-url
```

Where should I place this `Enable-SPFeature Ratings -url http://site-collection-url` ?

Comment: In a PowerShell window. This is question is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

That is a powershell command. And also apart from using powershell, you can write code in VS to activate rating.