# Social rating in SP 2010 - disapering votes

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I've enabled rating feature on my SP2010 site. I followed this material - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8b3dccba-1621-47d6-be2d-a47feb74b83f/how-do-i-display-sharepoint-ratings-rating-05-on-a-page?forum=sharepointdevelopmentlegacy
The only problem I had is missing Rating setting in list, which I fixed with PS as described here - [Enable Rating Feature Sharepoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047332/enable-rating-feature-sharepoint-2010).

The problem is that some ratings disappear after some time. E.g. Book in library has 7 votes yesterday and only one today. It wasn't just one accident - I received about 10 complaints.  Users can't cancel their votes - only change. Both sync timers set to 1 min.

Really dunno why this occurs - active googling haven't help me. Will be very grateful for any advice.